# wordpress text widget margin

Tags: css, widget, wordpress-theming

I'm getting stumped by a collapsing widget in twenty-twelve. The goal is to change the margins on sidebar widgets on [this page](http://pietroplace.com)

I added a text widget with an image and link titled "test" and another titled "second". What's happening as far as I can tell is the first text-widget is collapsing(to24px height), so when I go to add margins it's all messed up. Anyone tell me what's going on?

Comment: You'll need to add `float:left` to `.widget-area .widget`

Comment: @NickR that definitely did something. And though now the text-widgets really are collapsed, I can probably work with it. Can you explain what's going on there?